# 'ingredient for ' or 'ingredient of'?

Tags: prepositions

> 1)Mathematics acts as the most important ingredient for the discovery of Higgs Boson.
>
> 2)Mathematics acts as the most important ingredient of the discovery of Higgs Boson.
>
> 3)Mathematics acts as the most important ingredient in the discovery of Higgs Boson.

Is there a difference between the three sentences? Which version  is gramatically correct?

Comment: I don't think *ingredient* is what you want here. Maybe *influence* or *contributor*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the sentence should be in the simple past unless it's a headline of the paper.

Second, any of these prepositions is possible in the sentence, without any difference in meaning.  For example, you can say "Trust is a vital ingredient in/for/of a successful marriage.